# Styling p tags except for blockquotes

Tags: css, styles

How would I go about styling all p tags except for a p that is in a blockquote? Obviously I know I can have a style rule after I style all of the other p tags, but I feel there must be some other way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No. You can't target parent elements by children. You'll need ti style all `<p>` elements, and then reset them for `blockquote > p`.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but the question has an answer, and a really easy one: `p{....} blockquote p{....}` where blockquote's p is a reset or different style. Or am I understanding it all wrong?

Comment: @Fabio - The OP wanted a direct way of doing it, a *not child of* like selector.